# iframe delay resize

Tags: javascript, iframe

I use this code for auto resize my iframes http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing . Works just fine, but one problem occurred yesterday when I used search engine as iframe, as results take 0,5 to 1 seconds to show up, auto resize fail to size correctly the window so I think I need to delay script with 0.5 seconds. How can I do that ?

This is the code from iframe.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Set specific variable to represent all iframe tags.
    var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    // Resize heights.
    function iResize()
    {
        // Iterate through all iframes in the page.
        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++)
        {
            // Set inline style to equal the body height of the iframed content.
            iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames   [i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        }
    }

    // Check if browser is Safari or Opera.
    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera)
    {
        // Start timer when loaded.
        $('iframe').load(function()
            {
                setTimeout(iResize, 0);
            }
        );

        // Safari and Opera need a kick-start.
        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++)
        {
            var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
            iFrames[i].src = '';
            iFrames[i].src = iSource;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // For other good browsers.
        $('iframe').load(function()
            {
                // Set inline style to equal the body height of the iframed content.
                this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
            }
        );
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Which part do you want to delay? Your current `setTimeout` is passing 0 as an argument. Doesn't passing a number greater than 500 work?

Comment: I need delay for all browsers. I don't know what you mean by "which part" I want to delay. I need to delay resizing iframe because search results are slower. I should replace 0 with 500 here setTimeout(iResize, 0);   ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer exactly without seeing your html. You can either adjust `setTimout(iResize, 500);` which will check after 0.5 of a second.

OR, This is what I use when resizing a single iframe.

It will continue to check every 50ms to see if the body element has loaded.

```
function resizeIframe(iframe){
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument ||  iframe.contentWindow.document;
    if(doc.body){
        iframe.height =0;
        iframe.height = doc.body.scrollHeight + 30;
    }
    else{
         if(delay)clearTimeout(delay)
          delay = setTimeout(function(){resize(iframe)},50);
    }
};

var delay, iframe = document.getElementById('iFrame'); 


resizeIframe(iframe);
```

Comment: I remove it my script and tried to use yours with this iframe  <iframe id="my-iframe" name="my-iframe" align="left" src="../data/search-results" onload="resize()" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>  and replaced on your script 'iFrame' with 'my-iframe' but iframe is not showing at all.

Comment: Still getting hard to make it work right. http://jsfiddle.net/xaDZz/  I really need your code, its perfect for my needs as iframe size changes based on every search its perfect to check size every 50ms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mutationObserver to detect the changes in your page and trigger a resize of the iFrame.

Checkout this project on GitHub that will do this for you.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer